# :empty selector not working in @media print

Tags: css, printing, media-queries, selector

I work in Twig on symphony and have an empty div that should be hidden in print mode.

```
<div class="form-fields__list">
</div>
```

The thing is that on screen the :empty selector works just fine, but is being ignored in print mode. Even tried to wrap the block mentioned above in {% spaceless %} block in order to remove any possible whitespaces. Anyone have an idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

> The **:empty** pseudo selector will select elements that contain either nothing or only an HTML comment.

**Will Match**

```
<div></div>

<div><!-- test --></div>
```

---

**Will Not Match**

```
<div> </div>

<div>
  <!-- test -->
</div>

<div>
</div>
```

---

```css
.container {
  margin: 40px auto;
  max-width: 700px;
}

@media print {
  p:empty {
    background-color: linen;
    padding: 15px;
  }
}

.pseudo::before {
  content: "I am a piece of generated content inside a paragraph. The paragraph is still considered empty and gets a background color.";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, in, odit autem tempora fuga neque quos expedita repudiandae labore iure. Rem, blanditiis natus unde nisi explicabo odio pariatur maxime earum.
  </p>
  <p></p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque, tempora, ratione ad distinctio iusto illum accusamus qui porro inventore commodi voluptates tenetur dolor sed harum excepturi nemo aperiam beatae sint!
  </p>
  <p class="pseudo"></p>
  <p>
    <!-- COMMENT HERE -->
  </p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```